# multipal errors in a simple c# program regarding xml?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces

I am trying to compile a simple application in `c#` which will read from `XML` file .Here is my code and detail of errors which i am having

**Error1**

```
errors :Error   1   The type or namespace name 'XmlReader' could not be 
found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
c:\users\javed15\documents\visual studio 
2010\Projects\SalaryReader\SalaryReader\Program.cs  16  1   SalaryReader
```

**Error2**

```
2:Error     The name 'XmlReader' does not exist in the current context  
c:\users\javed15\documents\visual studio     
2010\Projects\SalaryReader\SalaryReader\Program.cs  16  20  SalaryReader
```

**Error3**

```
Error   3   The name 'XmlNodeType' does not exist in the current context    
c:\users\javed15\documents\visual studio 
2010\Projects\SalaryReader\SalaryReader\Program.cs  21  25  SalaryReader    
enter code here
```

**Code**

```
     using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace SalaryReader
{
    class Program
    {

static void Main(string[] args)
{
String XMLDataFilePath= @"C:\\XMLSalaries.xml";
String EmployeeName = "";
int varNoRecord = 0;
XmlReader Reader = XmlReader.Create(XMLDataFilePath);
Console.Write("Enter the Name of Person: ");
EmployeeName=Console.ReadLine();
while (Reader.Read()==true)
{
if ((Reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element))
{
if (Reader.HasAttributes & Reader.GetAttribute("Name")==EmployeeName)
{
Console.WriteLine("Salary Of " + Reader.GetAttribute("Name") + " = " + Reader.GetAttribute("CurrentSalary"));
varNoRecord = 1;
}
}
}
if (varNoRecord == 0)
Console.WriteLine("Oop! No Person with the name "+EmployeeName+" was found");
Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
Console.ReadKey(); 

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note that either `@"C:\XMLSalaries.xml"` or `"C:\\XMLSalaries.xml"` are correct, but `@"C:\\XMLSalaries.xml"` is wrong.

Comment: thank you sir .although i tried all variations which you pointed out but with no luck .